# Unable to get updated state after dispatching an async call from reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to get the updated state of users and store it in users' context after dispatching an action to an async call. I did get data in reducer function, but the state returned to my component doesn't change.

I'm putting the async call inside my reducer function and call useReducer in App.js. After that I provided both the state and dispatch from App.js to any component it may need it.

I might be doing something wrong because I'm still new to React. Here is my attempt:

```
// UserContext.js
import React from "react";

// create user context
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  status: "",
  message: "",
  username: "",
  password: "",
  users: []
});

export default UserContext;
```

```
// UserReducer.js
import axios from "axios";

// import action
import { AUTH_USER } from "./UserActionTypes";

// import endpoint
import { AUTH } from "../../constants";

// authenticate user
const authenticateUser = async (payload, state) => {
  // API call
  const response = await axios.post(`${AUTH}?type=${payload.type}`, {
    username: payload.username,
    password: payload.password
  });

  const data = response.data;

  console.log(`API Data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`); // data shown

  return {
    ...state,
    status: data.status,
    message: data.message,
    users: data.results
  };
};

const UserReducer = async (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_USER:
      const newState = await authenticateUser(action.payload, state);
      console.log(`New State: ${JSON.stringify(newState)}`); // new state shown
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default UserReducer;
```

```
// App.js
import UserContext from "./context/User/UserContext";
import UserReducer from "./context/User/UserReducer";

export default function App() {
  // initial state
  const initialState = {
    status: "",
    message: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
    users: []
  };

  // useReducer
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
// Login.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from "../../context/User/UserContext";
import { AUTH_USER } from "../../context/User/UserActionTypes";

const Login = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);

  // initail form data
  let initialForm = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    usernameError: null,
    passwordError: null
  };

  // useState
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm);

  // submit form
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!form.username) {
      setForm({ ...form, usernameError: "الرجاء إدخال اسم المستخدم" });
      return;
    }

    if (!form.password) {
      setForm({ ...form, passwordError: "الرجاء إدخال كلمة المرور" });
      return;
    }

    // dispatch auth action
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_USER,
      payload: {
        username: form.username,
        password: form.password,
        type: "db"
      }
    });

    console.log(`Context State: ${JSON.stringify(state)}`); // here (state) is still empty
  };

  return (
    <DirectionProvider direction={DIRECTIONS.RTL}>
      <div className="centered">
        <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <Pane>
            <TextInputField
              name="username"
              placeholder="اسم المستخدم"
              value={form.username || ""}
              onChange={e => {
                setForm({ ...form, username: e.target.value });
              }}
              validationMessage={form.usernameError}
            />
            <TextInputField
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="كلمة المرور"
              value={form.password || ""}
              onChange={e => {
                setForm({ ...form, password: e.target.value });
              }}
              validationMessage={form.passwordError}
            />
            <Button type="submit">
              تسجيل الدخول
            </Button>
          </Pane>
        </form>
      </div>
    </DirectionProvider>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I'm using:
react: "^16.12.0",
react-router: "^5.1.2",
react-router-dom: "^5.1.2",

Answer (score 3):

Reducers shouldn't be async and have any side effects, e.g. make api calls. All they do is apply changes to the state to produce a new state. They should be pure functions.

So in your case, you need to authenticate user outside of reducer and pass the result of that call to the reducer in order to compute the new state. Most likely you'll need to dispatch the actions that update the state from `authenticateUser`, which would need to be moved into `Login` component:

```
// submit form
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!form.username) {
      setForm({ ...form, usernameError: "الرجاء إدخال اسم المستخدم" });
      return;
    }

    if (!form.password) {
      setForm({ ...form, passwordError: "الرجاء إدخال كلمة المرور" });
      return;
    }

    const newState = await authenticateUser({
        username: form.username,
        password: form.password,
        type: "db"
      });

    // dispatch auth action
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_USER,
      payload: newState
    });
  };
```

```
const UserReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_USER:
      return {...state, ...action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Also remember that you're dispatching async actions here, so if you console.log the state right after dispatch, you'll still see the old value of the state. To check for the new value you could use `useEffect` hook for that, or move console.log outside of `handleSubmit`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state) // get updated value of the state
}, [state])
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work. Also, there is a syntax error in `return {...state, action.payload};`

Comment: Ah right, it'd be `{...state, ...action.payload}`. I'll update the answer.